# Create temp-table with twitter users aggregated text grouped by month

Tags: mysql, twitter, group-by

I have lots of tweets for users stored in MySQl. I´m trying to aggregate all tweet texts (text) for each user (from_user) and group them by month (created_at), like so:

```
from_user | month | fulltext
user1     | 1     | bla bla bla bla 
user1     | 2     | bleh bleh bleh
user2     | 1     | bla bla bla bla
user2     | 2     | blub blub blub
```

I´ve tried to write the SQL query like below, but I can´t figure out why MySQL is complaining. How should I solve this?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempsumdate;
CREATE TABLE tempsumdate ENGINE=MyISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci AS 
SELECT tw.from_user, MONTH(tw.created_at) AS month, GROUP_CONCAT(tw.text) AS fulltext  
FROM tweets AS tw
GROUP BY tw.from_user, month;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fulltext is a MySQL keyword. The following URL elaborates:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Try replacing `fulltext` with `` `fulltext` `` or just renaming it to something else all together.

My SQL fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c71e/2